# How to get base uri of referencing XAML in a custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml, uri

I have an custom control, which has an Image element with its Source property exposed to user, like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Source="{Binding ImageUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

where ImageUri is an property in the control class, like this:

```
public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }
```

This custom control is in an assembly `customcontrol.dll`, I can reference and use this control in an .exe with no problem, like this:

```
<cc:MyControl ImageUri="/Resources/Image.png" />
```

where `Image.png` is a resource of the .exe project.

But if I reference and use this control in an dll assembly, there is a problem, I have to use a absolute "pack://..." uri to reference an image in the calling dll, if I use an relative uri like "Resources/Image.png", the resource cant be loaded, it turns out, when this uri is applied on the Image element, it resolves the relative uri from `customcontrol.dll`, not the calling dll assembly, so I want to do this:

```
public Uri ImageUri {
    get { ...... }
    set {
        if (!value.IsAbsolute) {
            // Get the assembly name of parent xaml file or code
            // and construct a "pack://" uri from the assembly name
            // and value.OriginalString, but how ??????
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the assembly of the XAML code that uses my custom control?

If the control is used in code maybe I can use `GetCallingAssembly` in my methods, but XAML stuff is called from `PresontationCore.dll`, how can I find out the XAML assembly???

Answer (score 1):

OK I have found a solution myself. I should implement IUriContext interface,
which has only one property: Uri BaseUri, this is exactly what I want.